# How to set Nginx for both http and https requests

Tags: configuration, nginx

I need to set Nginx so it responds to http and https requests; I configured my default conf in this way:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       443;
  ssl           on;
  ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/certs/domain-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/certs/domain.it.key;
  server_name  static.domain.it;
  location / {
    try_files $uri @s3cache;
  }

  location @s3cache{
    proxy_cache            S3CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid      200 48h;
    proxy_cache_valid      403 60m;
    proxy_pass http://static.domain.it.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com;
  }
}
```

The https protocol works fine, but if I make an http request, I get this error:

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

Answer (score 7):

The [ssl](http://nginx.org/r/ssl) directive enables SSL for the whole vhost and does not look at the port number. If you want to restrict SSL to a single port, replace:

```
  listen       80;
  listen       443;
  ssl           on;
```

by:

```
  listen       80;
  listen       443 ssl;
```

See http://nginx.org/r/listen